# barman + corrupted wall + how it can be

Tags: postgresql, backup, linux, python, barman

I am using barman for bsackup version 2-1.1 and restore postgresql

first after 2 restore that was successfully 
I perform some show-backup on other backup , and I notices all backup return this errors: ( we have more then 50 backup's )

```
barman show-backup main-db-server  20170804T085002
EXCEPTION: ('Invalid LSN: %s', '00000001000000000000002B')
See log file for more details.
```

please help me to understand what is the problem here?
how it can be that all 50 backups suddenly are corrupted ?

it is no make sense !!!

from /var/log/barman I see the following

```
2017-08-04 10:37:47,824 [4256] barman.command_wrappers DEBUG: Command: 
'command(){ gzip -c -d > "$2" < "$1";}; command \'/var/lib/barman/main-db-
server/wals/00000008.history\' \'/var/lib/barman/main-db-
server/wals/.00000008.history.tQDDSb.uncompressed\''
2017-08-04 10:37:47,836 [4256] barman.command_wrappers DEBUG: Command return 
code: 0
2017-08-04 10:37:47,836 [4256] barman.command_wrappers DEBUG: Command 
stdout:
2017-08-04 10:37:47,836 [4256] barman.command_wrappers DEBUG: Command 
stderr:
2017-08-04 10:37:47,837 [4256] barman.cli ERROR: ('Invalid LSN: %s', 
'00000001000000000000002B')
See log file for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/cli.py", line 1041, in main
 p.dispatch(pre_call=global_config)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/helpers.py", line 47, in 
 dispatch
 return dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 121, in 
 dispatch
   for line in lines:
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 197, in 
  _execute_command
   for line in result:
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 153, in 
  _call
   result = args.function(args)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/cli.py", line 550, in 
   show_backup
   server.show_backup(backup_info)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/server.py", line 1688, in 
   show_backup
   backup_ext_info = self.get_backup_ext_info(backup_info)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/server.py", line 1674, in 
   get_backup_ext_info
   forked_after=backup_info.end_xlog)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/server.py", line 1853, in 
   get_children_timelines
   self.backup_manager.compression_manager)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/xlog.py", line 381, in 
   decode_history_file
   switchpoint=parse_lsn(contents[1]),
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/xlog.py", line 247, in 
   parse_lsn
   raise ValueError('Invalid LSN: %s', lsn_string)
   ValueError: ('Invalid LSN: %s', '00000001000000000000002B')
```

my sanity on barman server

```
    Server main-db-server:
    PostgreSQL: FAILED
    directories: OK
    retention policy settings: OK
    backup maximum age: OK (interval provided: 1 day, latest backup age: 1 
    hour, 54 minutes, 55 seconds)
    compression settings: OK
    failed backups: FAILED (there are 4 failed backups)
    minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 69 backups, expected at least 
     0)
    ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
    not in recovery: OK
    archiver errors: OK
```

my crontab:

```
crontab -l
30 23 * * * /usr/bin/barman backup main-db-server
 * * * * * /usr/bin/barman cron
```

I use rsync as appears in postgresql file

```
 archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@109.56.34.32:/var/lib/barman/main-db-server/incoming/%f'
```

Comment: Could you add the content of the log file please ?